# Yii's infinite-scroll-pager extension doesn't show pager

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I am using the Yii's extension [infinite-scroll-pager](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/inifinite-scroll-pager/). My data provider has 6 registers, but I want it to show only the first 3. How can I get it done? Would the `triggerPageTreshold` (*sic*) have to do this job?

```
$listView = $this->widget(
    'zii.widgets.CListView',
    array(
        'id' => 'activities-scroll-list',
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'itemView' => '/experience/_experience_item',
        'cssFile' => null,
        'template' => $this->renderPartial(
                '/experience/_experiences_list',
                array(),
                true
        ),
        'pager' => array(
            'id' => 'pager-id',
            'class' => 'ext.infiniteScroll.IasPager',
            'rowSelector' => '.row',
            'listViewId' => 'activities-scroll-list',
            'header' => 'TESTE',
            'loaderText' => 'Loading...',
            'options' => array(
                'history' => true,
                'triggerPageTreshold' => 3,
                'trigger' => 'Load more'
            )
        ),
    )
);
```

The `/experience/_experiences_list`:

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="home-experience-resume" class="wrapper-k">
<?php
        echo '{summary} {items} {pager}';
?>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `/experience/_experience_item`:

```
<article class="column-3 <?= ((($index - 1) % 3) == 0 ? 'middle' : ''); ?> equal-height">
    <div class="inner-wrapper">
        <div class="img-container">
            <img  src="/images/tmp_thumbExperiencia1.jpg" alt="<?php echo Yii::t('home','Experiência 1'); ?>" />
        </div>
        <div class="info-column-container">
            <div class="info-column">
                <p class="more-detail-link">
                    <img src="/images/experiences/iconLocal.png" alt="icon local"/>
                    <a href="#" target="_self"><?= $data->showingCity; ?></a>
                </p>
                <h3><?= $data->name; ?></h3>
                <a class="button bt-small" href="/experience/info/<?php echo $data->id; ?>" target="_self"><?= Yii::t('home','Saber mais'); ?></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
'template' => '<div class="row">div id="home-experience-resume" class="wrapper-k"> {summary} {items} {pager} </div></div>',
```